# react native fbsdk how can I get a long live access token via a server

Tags: facebook, react-native-fbsdk

I am using native-fbsdk for Facebook login, once I sign in using **LoginButton**, I get the access token using this code:

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {AccessToken} = FBSDK;
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
.then(
      (data) => {
          alert(data.accessToken.toString())
      }
)
```

I get the access token but I don't know if it is a long live or a short live access token, how can I get a long live using a short live access token:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/portability

I saw in this link that it is possible to get long live access token giving a short live access token to a server but I don't know how to do it on react native.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official page to generate long-lived token from a server [Fb Long-lived token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/#generate-long-lived-token)

In the page [fb access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/), the following is indicated.

> Mobile apps that use Facebook's iOS and Android SDKs get long-lived tokens by default.